# How Long Will Your Smartphone Distract You From Family Dinner?

Tags: c#, simulation

I wrote a program to simulate this week's 538 [Riddler](http://fivethirtyeight.com/features/how-long-will-your-smartphone-distract-you-from-family-dinner/), reproduced below:

> You’ve just finished unwrapping your holiday presents. You and your
>   sister got brand-new smartphones, opening them at the same moment. You
>   immediately both start doing important tasks on the Internet, and each
>   task you do takes one to five minutes. (All tasks take exactly one,
>   two, three, four or five minutes, with an equal probability of each).
>
> After each task, you have a brief moment of clarity. During these, you
>   remember that you and your sister are supposed to join the rest of the
>   family for dinner and that you promised each other you’d arrive
>   together. You ask if your sister is ready to eat, but if she is still
>   in the middle of a task, she asks for time to finish it. In that case,
>   *you* now have time to kill, so you start a new task (again, it will
>   take one, two, three, four or five minutes, exactly, with an equal
>   probability of each). If she asks you if it’s time for dinner while
>   you’re still busy, you ask for time to finish up and she starts a new
>   task and so on.
>
> From the moment you first open your gifts, *how long on
>   average does it take for both of you to be between tasks at the same
>   time so you can finally eat?* (You can assume the “moments of clarity”
>   are so brief as to take no measurable time at all.)

And the program itself:

```
private static int numberOfSimulations = 100000;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var rand = new Random();
    var simulationTimes = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSimulations; i++)
    {
        var totalTime = 0;
        var myTaskTime = rand.Next(1, 6);
        var herTaskTime = rand.Next(1, 6);

        do
        {
            if (herTaskTime > myTaskTime)
            {
                totalTime += myTaskTime;
                herTaskTime -= myTaskTime;
                myTaskTime = rand.Next(1, 6);
            }
            else if (herTaskTime < myTaskTime)
            {
                totalTime += herTaskTime;
                myTaskTime -= herTaskTime;
                herTaskTime = rand.Next(1, 6);
            }
            else
            {
                totalTime += myTaskTime;
            }
        } while (myTaskTime - herTaskTime != 0);

        simulationTimes.Add(totalTime);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(simulationTimes.Average());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Anecdotally, I'm consistently getting ~7.5 minutes.

I'm just looking for a general code review - does this look correct? Am I doing anything dumb? Should I have done it differently?

Comment: _"I'm consistently getting ~7.5 minutes."_ And that's wrong or what? What are you asking to be reviewed/improved actually?

Comment: That's more anecdotal than anything, maybe I should have specified that. I'm just looking for a general review - does this look correct? Am I doing anything dumb? Should I have done it differently?

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think your code is flawed. You assign new tasks even if the current task is not confirmed completed. You need to check if `myTaskTime` and/or `herTaskTime` is zero before assigning a new task. Here's a quick and very dirty example (avg. ~9): https://dotnetfiddle.net/goaWaI

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå you could very well be right. The logic here is treating the `if/else if` as allowing the shorter task to elapse (remove the remaining time from the other's task, assign a new task). I'm taking a look at your approach now, trying to figure out where the difference is

Comment: The difference *might* be related to the fact that the `do` statement terminates if `rand.Next` generates a value that meets the `myTaskTime - herTaskTime == 0` condition, thus the last task time is not added to the total.

Comment: fwiw, I get the same answer in my testing, and it's in line with what my attempt to figure it out by logic suggests.  So the output is probably right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's definitely an issue that will occur when a new task comes up with the same amount of time as what is left on the other person's task. Take for example the times.

```
MyTime | HerTime
----------------
3      | 5
```

Now the first loop occurs, `HerTime` gets reduced to 2, `TotalTime` gets set to 3, then `MyTime` gets rerolled to 2. Now, your while condition hits as `MyTime = HerTime` and it breaks out, but those 2 minutes were never accounted for.

An easy fix would be to add a guard condition to your while that gets set in the Else part of your If.

(Warning, the below changes are untested air code)

```
private static int numberOfSimulations = 100000;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var rand = new Random();
    var simulationTimes = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSimulations; i++)
    {
        var totalTime = 0;
        var myTaskTime = rand.Next(1, 6);
        var herTaskTime = rand.Next(1, 6);
        var equal = false;

        do
        {
            if (herTaskTime > myTaskTime)
            {
                totalTime += myTaskTime;
                herTaskTime -= myTaskTime;
                myTaskTime = rand.Next(1, 6);
            }
            else if (herTaskTime < myTaskTime)
            {
                totalTime += herTaskTime;
                myTaskTime -= herTaskTime;
                herTaskTime = rand.Next(1, 6);
            }
            else
            {
                totalTime += myTaskTime;
                equal = true;
            }
        } while (!equal);

        simulationTimes.Add(totalTime);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(simulationTimes.Average());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Ah, yep. When I incorporate these changes I'm getting 9 now as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty readable.  I would make the following suggestions: move the code in the `for` loop into a separate function, called something like `RunSimulation`.  Define constants for the 1 and 6 you have sprinkled around and/or make task creation a separate function.

```
while (myTaskTime - herTaskTime != 0)
```

This is strange, is there a reason it's not

```
while (myTaskTime != herTaskTime)
```

Comment: I think I had a reason for that when I wrote it this morning but I can't remember what it was now. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`